# KiCAD - plethora of errors when performing ERC

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

I finally finished my first schematic and everything looked great.
I went ahead to perform Electrical Rules Check.

There were many errors.

Most of them were:

> Pin connected to other pins, but not driven by any pin.

> Pin not connected (use a "No-connection" flag to suppress this error).

I used bi-directional pins exclusively.

Also note that I used the Arduino shield template. Maybe I had to declare all pins not used as NC?

If you want, I can upload the schematic file somewhere.

EDIT: Here is a picture of the schematic.

[image]

Comment: You can try this out yourself without asking here. Do it in a limited way on one chip then bingo; see what happens. Do the errors reduce in number?

Comment: @Andyaka try what exactly? I declare all pins i did not use as NC. The arduino pins are way to many. Do i have to declare all of them NC? Maybe if declaring them as NC will break something since it is a shield? In one video i saw, he didn't label the header pins as NC.

Comment: with 533 reputation, you should be able to include images directly in your question – So, what I usually do is using "plot" to write the schematic to an SVG file, and then hosting that myself and just `<img src="https://url.of.my.image/file.svg" alt="schematic image">` in the post, or I open the SVG in Inkscape and export as PNG, and upload it directly using the "upload image" button in the post editor here.

Comment: @user1584421 you're missing Andy's point. While they certainly are many, it's easy to just compare the results of two DRC runs ofter just changing *one* thing. (if in doubt, the `diff`tool is very mighty).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks. I exported to svg but the image is weird. Like a checkerboard. Should i upload this photo?

Comment: @user1584421 there's no checkerboard in the SVG, that's probably your viewer. It has a reason I recommended inkscape.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited the question and i included a picture. It is the result of a print screen. I tried to convert the svg, but even the pngs that were produced had that checkerboard background which was difficult to look at. I used online tools to generate the afforementioned png.

Comment: @user1584421 pretty! (again, the checkerboard isn't in the image itself, it's by your viewers for SVG and PNG files, pretty certainly.)

Comment: @user1584421 That checkerboard is a pretty standard way of indicating transparency in image editors that support transparency (such as svg and png); it won't show up as checkerboard when posted to a website.

Comment: @Hearth Should i upload it then? Because i think the one i already uploaded looks ok. If you want, i will upload the other.

Comment: @user1584421 The one you uploaded now is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the circuit and where the ECR arrows are pointing I can see two type of violations

1. undriven net
2. Power flag

P1, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7 have pins that do not connect to anything. You are obviously labeling them to align to the Mega but from the perspective of this circuit they are unconnected. The intent of this ECR is to ensure you don't leave unconnected nets ... unconnected.  If you intend to leave it unconnected us the "no connect" flag at the end of the net (the blue cross)

You have a couple of global powerflags (3v3, 5v, GND) but KiCAD does not know these are power, use the power_flag to inform kicad this is a powernet

**Dangling nets:**

if you are 100% sure a net is to be unconnected, add the NC to each one

[image]

**Power-Nodes**

if you are using power symbols that do connect to a pin that expects POWER-IN, inform Kicad that this is a power source

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am new to KiCAD, and i am trying to understand what you just said. I do not exactly understand which {P1, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7} you are refering to. This is the arduino MEGA template, i just connected some pins that connect to my circuit. The green arrows are too many, should i label every pin where is a green arrow as NC? Then about the powerflags. There are two power signals in my circuit. Both coming from the coaxial connector (+arduino GND, but it also connects to the coaxial connector, so i said two). Should i just label the two lines that touch the connector? Is this enough?

Comment: @user1584421 thats not too many ;)  I had over 300 when I was dealing with an FPGA recently.  To permit the ECR to complete a net must connect to two nodes. Dangling nets could indicate an incomplete circuit or an intentional no-connect. add a NC to each one to inform the checker of your intentions. The POWER-NODE. I am speculating here as you have not provided the infomation

Comment: my objection is not the work to do. I just ask, should i mark all the arduino pins that are not connected as NC? And about the labels.. Marking the signals that connect to the two poles of the power jack will be enough? Thanks again!